# Office integration (Word) - intercepting save

Tags: ms-word, vsto, ms-office

I am planning to implement a small in-house document management system. It must have a web GUI for managing a remote folder structure stored in a database. In these folders are word documents stored (physically as blob in a database). Whenever a user clicks on a document link, a word binary is downloaded via browser and (hopefully) opened in Word on the user's PC.

This is the easy part ;)

Now the user hits "Save" or Ctrl-S. I want to have a functionality programmed inside Word that calls a custom function (maybe in a .NET DLL) that uploads the saved file back to the server (HTTP). The hard part seems to me:

- How to intercept the Save process to call the extension functionality
- How to deploy this to multiple users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Mike's link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1415918/41153) to [the question I answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374029/handle-file-new-in-word-2007) should do it for intercepting the file save. The specific button idMso for `File->Save` is "FileSave"

To deploy it to several users machine you can either

1. Create a setup project that will create an msi that you can run on all the users machines
2. if it's an intranet scenario, you can keep the assemblies on a network location and just add the neceassary registry settings to all the users machines.  This [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/mshneer/archive/2007/09/04/deploying-your-vsto-add-in-to-all-users-part-i.aspx) should describe the settings that you need to include. You would just need to change the path setting to point to the network location.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, this is what [Alfresco](http://www.alfresco.com/) is doing with its [Microsoft Office Add-ins](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Microsoft_Office) (never tested myself though). As Alfresco is open-source, it must be possible to look at what they are doing. Or just ask your questions on Alfresco's [forums](http://forums.alfresco.com/en/viewforum.php?f=47&sid=f472f74418e452515d3ce3e9d54e85a3).

Comment: Here's the [Alfresco MS Office 2003 Plugin](http://code.google.com/p/alfresco-ms-office-plugin/) (now not officially supported as Alfresco for Office 2007+ uses the Sharepoint protocol.)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to override "save" from the ribbon or build your own ribbon tab with the behavior you want. It may be trickier overriding "Ctrl-S".

Overriding the ribbon: [StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374029/handle-file-new-in-word-2007)

Video on altering a standard ribbon button: [Office Developer Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dd361753.aspx)