# How to customize save behaviour in Word using VSTO

Tags: vsto, add-in

Fundamental question on how to get the bits to work together: I've not used VSTO before and after 4 hrs of searching I've decided to ask!

I want to create a simple AddIn for word that will execute when the user saves ANY document.

I *thought* all I would need to do would be to create an AddIn in VisualStudio 2008, and put my code in the ThisAddIn class

```
 Public WithEvents objWordApp As Word.Application

    Private Sub objWordApp_DocumentBeforeSave(ByVal Doc As Word.Document, ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, ByVal Cancel As Boolean)
        MsgBox("my addin code is running")
    End Sub
```

and that would be that. Only this never gets run.

There is a clue here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb221264.aspx that I have failed to declare the object, but I have no idea if this is what I am missing, or if it is, where that declaration code would go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the VSTO specific event handler for "BeforeSave" (with example): [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.word.saveeventhandler.aspx)

If you want to completely override the File > Save behavior of word, please reference these Stackoverflow questions:

[Office integration (Word) - intercepting save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415316/office-integration-word-intercepting-save/1415918#1415918)
[Handle File->New in Word 2007](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374029/handle-file-new-in-word-2007)

Comment: Those combined with http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442981.aspx have got me going. Thanks Mike.