# how could i know that the user clicked File->Save in word document using .NET?

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

How could I know that the user clicked File Save in word document using .NET?

If user make any action in word document then i can know what this event in my program
that made using c#.

Comment: now this is a strange language...

Comment: @precious: there's no such thing as "C#.net".

Comment: what version of word? the answer could be different.

Answer (score 1):

If you're creating a C# VSTO addin, you can intercept the document SAVE or SAVEAS events.

Check this thread for details

[How to customize save behaviour in Word using VSTO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887368/how-to-customize-save-behaviour-in-word-using-vsto)