# How to use VBA to change the default MS Word 2016 options so that when you save as PDF the headings are included as bookmarks?

Tags: vba, ms-word, pdf-generation

I'm using Microsoft Word 2016 and looking for a way to run a vba macro that will change the default option to `Create bookmarks using: Headings` when I save a document as PDF when I click on

1. File ->
2. Save As ->
3. PDF (*.pdf) ->
4. More options.. ->
5. Options

[image: Create bookmarks using]

Note: The option is only available if you have a table of contents in the document.

**The goal is that if a user chooses to save as PDF that option will be already checked.**

---

I'm not asking how to do this manually, like in this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/95222/from-word-to-pdf-including-bookmarks)

***nor*** programmaticaly save to PDF using vba like [here](http://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/32224-save-pdf-bookmarks.html) or [here](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?54602-Vba-code-to-save-document-as-pdf-using-document-property-text-and-rename-folder).

Comment: Where is this option ("Create bookmarks using:") found in Word?

Comment: Have you tried recording the steps (whatever they are) as a macro?

Comment: I think you're talking about an option that comes with  the **"Microsoft PDF Add-In"** (which appears to be no longer available, from Microsoft anyway).  Do you have this add-in?

Comment: @ashleedawg File -> Save As -> PDF (*.pdf) -> More options.. -> Options

Comment: @CindyMeister yes have tried that, these option changes are not captured by the macro recording process.

Comment: Have you looked for it in the registry?

Comment: Which version of Microsoft Word do you use?

Comment: @BrunoBieri Word 2016

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's not reachable by VBA at the point of save a file as PDF I do not see it as possible to change that PDF saving option using only VBA.

The only way I see you can reach the behavior you seek is as follow but need some special effort. You need to either create a VTSO addin or be able to have an extra marco file in the Microsoft Word Startup-Path so it will be loaded at Microsoft Word Startup.

- Re-implement your own "Save" behavior by overriding the Save functionality (`BeforeSave`) of Microsoft Word and provide it via your own Save-Button in the Microsoft Word-Menu described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887368/how-to-customize-save-behaviour-in-word-using-vsto)