# Dynamically Customizing the Built-In Office 2007 Ribbon

Tags: c#, vsto, ribbon, office-2007

I'm trying to dynamically customize the built-in Ribbon Controls on an Office2007 ribbon by adding C# objects such as `RibbonTab`, `RibbonGroup`, `RibbonControl` to the Ribbon.  I have been unsuccessfull in disabeling any existing built-in controls, however I can add my own group.  Now i'm thinking that disabling or hiding existing ones not be possible.

If anyone been able to hide a built-in control using code or the designer using .NET VSTO Office 2007 development, can you please post the code you used?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374029/handle-file-new-in-word-2007) question that talks about overriding built-in ribbon commands. Here is an [MSDN video](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dd361753.aspx) that shows it as well.

Comment: Thank you for the reply as I am able to hide a built-in Ribbon Group uising the Ribbon.xml and overidding the IRibbonExtensibility CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject() within the application.  

However, I am not able to do the same dynamically using the Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonGroup class.  Althouh I am able to hide built in tabs via the Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonTab class.  Any suggestions on how I can hide a built-in Group using the Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonGroup class?